# Simple Circuits- negative voltage vs current flow

Tags: voltage, current

Say I have a voltage source of -5V. Does the fact that the voltage is negative impact which way the current flows? It seems like a silly question because from what i've already researched I don't think it has any impact.

Comment: A voltage source with a larger magnitude placed reversed in series can cause current to flow in the opposite direction regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Conventional current flows from the more positive terminal of the voltage source, through the circuit, and returns to the more negative terminal, regardless of where in the circuit you choose to call "zero volts" or "ground".